What is the concentration level of dissolved oxygen in the mesopelagic zone?
Somehow, I can find multiple references for dissolved O2 levels (usually in mg/L) for the epipelagic, bathypelagic and abyssopelagic zones of the ocean, but not the mesopelagic...
One might naively assume that the level is between the epipelagic and bathypelagic, but a couple of sites implied that it is lower than either...
